# Using Windows Bluetooth API on OS X/Mac?

Tags: c++, windows, macos, qt, bluetooth

I'm using Qt for a Bluetooth class on Windows, which links to ws2_32.lib, and includes winsock2.h, ws2bth.h, BluetoothAPIs.h. However, I wanna also run this Qt source project on OS X, I know I have to change some source code to make it compatible to OS X, but I don't have a clue on where to start with, can this be achieved by just minor modifications? or it’s necessary to start from scratch?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [QtBluetooth](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtbluetooth-index.html) module currently supports Android, BlackBerry 10 and Linux (Bluez 4.x) and indeed, OS X and Windows are not supported yet.

You should write the bluetooth functionality you need in XCode and then import it into your Qt project as a linked library. You can also have a library in which you use platform specific macros like `#ifdef Q_OS_WIN` and `#ifdef q_os_osx` and put your platform specific code in relevant defs.